# Bridged network between Ubuntu Desktop 10.10 host and Ubuntu Server 10.10 Guest

Tags: networking, virtualbox, network-bridge

I run Ubuntu 10.10 Desktop on my machine and have installed Ubuntu Server 10.10 in a Virtualbox VM. I'm running Virtualbox 4.0.2. It is not virtualbox-ose.

I'd like the guest OS to have an IP address on my local network so that I can run server software and access this from the host OS. My intention is to run a Hudson CI server in the guest OS.

I understand I need to set up a network bridge for this to work, however I don't understand what I need to do for this to happen.

I have tried following the instructions at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/Networking, however I run into two issues towards the end:

1. "To take the modifications into account, restart the VirtualBox host networking script". I don't have Virtualbox-ose installed and guide suggests `sudo /etc/init.d/vboxnet restart`, however `/etc/init.d/vboxnet` does not exist for me.
2. The end of the guide refers to the `vboxusers` group. I don't have such a group and am not sure why I need this or how it should be created.

I'm simply looking to allow the guest OS to have an IP on my local network so that I can access servers on the guest OS from the host OS.

What changes do I need to make to both the host and guest OSs for this to work?

Answer (score 1):

In https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/Networking
you can read

Version 2.1 has reimplemented some of its networking. Bridging a virtual machine can now be done entirely from the graphical user interface.

Therefore the page apply only to 2.0 version, 2.1 and onward the bridging is entirly manged from the gui.

Comment: To be as clear as possible. Just select 'Bridge' in the VirtualBox machine configuration. Everything is automatic now.